# Create MongoDB document with non-string values in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I can't for the life of me create a MongoDB document in Java with values that aren't Strings. I've tried using the "put" and "append" method, both return an error similar to the one below.

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
doc.put("foo", "bar"); // this works
doc.put("ugh", 5); // this doesn't
doc.put("plz", 7L); // nor does this

// [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project league: Compilation failure
// [ERROR] /home/calvin/league/src/main/java/gg/bram/league/App.java:[60,19] error: no suitable method found for put(String,int)
// Relevant bit: "error: no suitable method found for put(String,int)"
```

Output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-5~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Using mongo-java-driver 2.12.4, proof in pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is killing me, I'm doing nothing different from all the tutorials/docs I can find online, please help!!

Thanks

EDIT: My entire pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>gg.bram.league</groupId>
  <artifactId>league</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>league</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>gg.bram.league.App</mainClass>
              <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>true</classpathMavenRepositoryLayout>
              <classpathPrefix>/home/calvin/.m2/repository/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Show your entire POM. I suspect that you're compiling with a 1.4 compliance level, which means you aren't getting autoboxing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your source and target set in the wrong place; they should be on `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: The best answers are those that make me feel dumb. Thanks for the quick fix!